# Whether the `v.` means both `vi.` and `vt.`?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

Does the "v." in a dictionary mean both "vi." and "vt."?

We know in dictionary, "vi." means intransitive verbs, and "vt." means "transitive verbs", but I often see "v." in dictionary. Does it means both?

Comment: Can you share an example? Which dictionary did you see this in?

Comment: It depends on the dictionary. Some dictionaries just say "verb" and don't mention whether it's transitive or intransitive. In other dictionaries, if a verb is both vi and vt, it defines the verb up top as a "v.", then in the definitions below, it distinguishes between vt and vi definitions, like [this entry for "tell" in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell).

Comment: @gotube Thanks.